# Broadcasting algebraic operations between dicts

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have two dicts and I want to subtract the matching values from the two dicts to generate a third dict.

```
A = Dict("w" => 2, "x" => 3)
B = Dict("x" => 5, "w" => 7)
# Ideally I could go B .- A and get a dict like 
C = Dict("w" => 5, "x" => 2)
# but I get ERROR: ArgumentError: broadcasting over dictionaries and `NamedTuple`s is reserved
```

One ugly solution is to overload the subtraction operator but I am not keen to overload for a builtin type like dict for fear of breaking other code.

```
import Base.-
function -(dictA::Dict, dictB::Dict)
   keys_of_A = keys(dictA)
   subtractions = get.(Ref(dictB), keys_of_A, 0) .- get.(Ref(dictA), keys_of_A, 0)
   return Dict(keys_of_A .=> subtractions)
end
```

#### Is there a cleaner way to do algebraic operations on matching values from different dicts?

Comment: I'd define a function like `apply_f_common(f::Function, d1::Dict, d2::Dict)`, where `f` is applied to all values with common keys. That way you can write `apply_f_common(-, d1, d2)` and it is syntactically obvious what is happening. I don't think broadcasting would be a good syntactic solution here, since intrinsic to broadcasting is the idea that the inputs can be cast to a common size. Similarly, intrinsic to `-` is the idea that the inputs are a common size. Neither of these are guaranteed with two dicts as input.

Comment: You might find the [`DataStructures`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl) package useful.  After `using DataStructures`, `C = merge(-, B, A)` gives the desired result from your example.

Comment: No need for `DataStructures` to do that.

Comment: I don't really want to use a separate package as it seems a bit of overkill as I can also write a function in base Julia to do it. I was just hoping there was a cleaner way to do it rather than writing the function though. @ColinTBowers, it doesn't seem to me that there is a big difference between dicts and arrays here. Neither is assured to be of same size in the basic B .- A case (although you get an error if they are not). With arrays you match elements through the indexes and for dicts you can match with keys.

Comment: Applying `-` to two arrays of the same size gives an array of the same size or an error. Applying `.-` to two arrays of different sizes will cast one array up to the size of the other or give an error. Basically, output sizes are guaranteed to match or an error is thrown. In the `Dict` case, the output might be the same size, might be smaller, might be empty. So I think it is sensible to syntactically distinguish it, which `merge` does, so now that I know about it I definitely think it is the right solution - as @fredrikekre points out, it will work for any collection so no extra package.

Comment: I guess I don't know what "cleaner" means here.

Comment: Yeah I think merge is the correct answer actually. Sorry I thought it was an export of DataStructures. Thanks

Comment: Ha!  So did I!  Thanks for showing me what I was showing you.  :)

Comment: @rickhg12hs So, could one of you please post this as an answer? Then it gets preserved for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`merge`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/base/collections/#Base.merge) provides the result you want.

```julia
A = Dict("w" => 2, "x" => 3)
B = Dict("x" => 5, "w" => 7)
C = merge(-, B, A)

Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "w" => 5
  "x" => 2
```

Note that `merge` performs a union of the two collections and combines common keys by performing the given operation. So, for example:

```julia
W = Dict("w" => 4)
merge(-, B, W)

Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "w" => 3
  "x" => 5
```

Comment: That's neat.  Not something I remember from Python dicts.